# Ran out of short values to detect collision in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am using short values to detect collision in my LIBGDX game, but I have placed so many elements that I have ran out of values. I am currently at 32768 which is recognized as integer. What do I do?

These are my collision bits:

```
public static final short NOTHING_BIT = 0;
public static final short GROUND_BIT = 1;
public static final short FRAN_BIT = 2;
public static final short BRICK_BIT = 4;
public static final short SECONDS_BIT = 8;
public static final short DESTROYED_BIT = 16;
public static final short HIDDEN_BIT = 32;
public static final short ENEMY_BIT = 64;
public static final short ENEMY_HEAD_BIT = 128;
public static final short ENEMY_FRONT_BIT = 256;
public static final short FRAN_HEAD_BIT = 512;
public static final short FRAN_BODY_SENSOR_BIT = 1024;
public static final short ENEMY_LIMIT = 2048;
public static final short WATER_BIT = 4096;
public static final short FIREBALL_BIT = 8192;
public static final short GROUND_ESCAPE = 16384;
```

This is the code where collision is detected:

```
 @Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    int cDef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;

    switch (cDef){

        case JungleMasters.FRAN_HEAD_BIT | JungleMasters.BRICK_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == JungleMasters.FRAN_HEAD_BIT){
                ((InteractiveTIleObject)fixB.getUserData()).onHeadHit((Franfran) fixA.getUserData());
            } else {
                ((InteractiveTIleObject) fixA.getUserData()).onHeadHit((Franfran) fixB.getUserData());
            }

            sound = screen.assetManager.manager.get(screen.assetManager.brickBreaking);
            sound.play();

            break;

        case JungleMasters.FRAN_HEAD_BIT | JungleMasters.HIDDEN_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == JungleMasters.FRAN_HEAD_BIT){
                ((InteractiveTIleObject)fixB.getUserData()).onHeadHit((Franfran) fixA.getUserData());
            } else {
                ((InteractiveTIleObject) fixA.getUserData()).onHeadHit((Franfran) fixB.getUserData());
            }

            sound = screen.assetManager.manager.get(screen.assetManager.brickBreaking);
            sound.play();

            break; ...}
```

Comment: Why can't you just change all the shorts to ints?

Comment: @Rick `categoryBits` and `maskBits` are `short`s. So it doesn't work with int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `categoryBits` and `maskBits` are primarly for box2d to say which fixture collide with which other fixture.

So when one of your `fixtures` collide with all or none `fixture` you don't need `category`- or `maskBits` for it.

If the fixture collide with all of the other fixtures you don't need `category`- or `maskBits`.
If the fixture collide with none of the other fixtures you can set `isSensor = true;` instead of using `category`- and `maskBits`.

If you will know which object has collided with an other object you can use the `UserData` of fixtures.

Create a Enum for all Types you have:

```
public enum Type {
    NOTHING,
    GROUND,
    FRAN,
    FRAN_BODY_SENSOR,
    ENEMY_FRONT,
    BRICK,
    etc...
}
```

And then by creating the fixture you can set the Type as UserData:

```
Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
fixture.setUserData(Type.GROUND);
//short:
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(Type.GROUND);
```

Finally in your `ContactListener` you can check the UserData of fixture to find out which object collide with which other:

```
if(fixA.getUserData() == Type.FRAN_HEAD && fixB.getUserData() == Type.BRICK){
            //FRAN_HEAD and BRICK has collided
}
```